# Ignore properties of class by comparing with a list in c#

Tags: c#, list, filtering

I have a list where TestClass is a class with some predefined properties. So when i get data and bind my list with data i need to ignore some properties of TestClass by comparing it with a list. How can i achieve that?

Below is my code

```
    public class TestClass
{
 public int id{get;set;}
 public string fname{get;set;} 
public string lname{get;set;}
public string job {get;set;}
public string role{get;set;}
public string address{get;set;}
}



List<TestClass> ulist = null;
   ulist = ToList<TestClass>(usersdataset.tables[0]); //fill my list with the data code is given below
```

so after getting the data into the list i need to remove some properties by comparing it with list of properties which should be returned.for example if my filteredlist should only show id,fname,role then i need to remove the extra properties from my **ulist**. so after the filter ulist should only contain id,fname and role

**ToList Method**

```
public static List<T> ToList<T>(DataTable dataTable) where T : new()
        {
            var dataList = new List<T>();

            //Define what attributes to be read from the class
            const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;

            //Read Attribute Names and Types
            var objFieldNames = typeof(T).GetProperties(flags).Cast<PropertyInfo>().
                Select(item => new
                {
                    Name = item.Name,
                    Type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(item.PropertyType) ?? item.PropertyType
                }).ToList();

            //Read Datatable column names and types
            var dtlFieldNames = dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                Select(item => new {
                    Name = item.ColumnName,
                    Type = item.DataType
                }).ToList();

            foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.AsEnumerable().ToList())
            {
                var classObj = new T();

                foreach (var dtField in dtlFieldNames)
                {
                    PropertyInfo propertyInfos = classObj.GetType().GetProperty(dtField.Name);

                    var field = objFieldNames.Find(x => x.Name == dtField.Name);
                    //var field = filteredColumns.Find(x => x.PropertyName == dtField.Name);
                    if (field != null)
                    {
                        if (dataRow[dtField.Name] != DBNull.Value)
                            propertyInfos.SetValue(classObj, dataRow[dtField.Name], null);
                    }   

                }                   
                dataList.Add(classObj);
            }
            return dataList;
        }
```

Comment: what's is wrong with your code?  I can see where it can be more succinct and efficient but is it causing an error?  What exactly are you looking for help on

Comment: Can you pass a `List<string>` to `ToList` which contains a list of properties names you want to ignore? Then in your loop `foreach (var dtField in dtlFieldNames.Where(f => !ignoreList.Contains(f))` then you would never have filled them in. Otherwise you are going to have to use reflection again to loop over each item in your list and null out each of the properties one by one, using Reflection `GetProperties` again

Comment: Just a note: since `T` remains the same for the entire function, you don't need the `PropertyInfo propertyinfos = classObj...` line in your loop. Move it out to the top `var props = typeof(T).GetProperties(flags).ToDictionary(x => x.Name)` and then replace the line in your loop with something like `var propertyInfos = props[dtField.Name];` this way you can keep reusing the PropertyInfo object without have to keep looking it up with Reflection (despite being different objects, the PropertyInfo object is the same--hence the 1st param to `SetValue()` where you specify the object to call it on)

Answer (score -1):

Use the overvride function Equals: 
This sample compare only the id property

```
public class TestClass
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string fname { get; set; }
        public string lname { get; set; }
        public string job { get; set; }
        public string role { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj.GetType().Name != this.GetType().Name)
            {
                return false;
            }
            TestClass testclassObject = (TestClass)obj;
            if (testclassObject.id != this.id)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```